# How to deserialize JSON type with key-based type properties?

Tags: java, json

I want to use Jackson Mapper to deserialize a JSON that looks like this

```
"parameters": {
            "bodyParameter": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "otherParam": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "uuid": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
```

to a java.util.List of simple POJO like this

```
public class Parameter {

    String name;

    String type;
}
```

I would therefor expect 3 instances of type Parameter, first would contain name="bodyParameter" and type="String", and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jacksonJson library for this.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

PsuedoCode:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> dataMap = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

The dataMap will have the key-value pairs. Iterate the entrySet and assign the values to your POJO

Comment: Thank you but still had to do the whole custom serializer/ deserializer work :(

Answer (score 0):

To have this working in terms of serialization/ deserialization I had to got with Jackson's custom support

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ParametersDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = ParametersSerializer.class)
private List<Parameter> parameter;
```

The custom deserializer would basically loop the JSON "parameters" node fields and return the parameters list

```
JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
List<Parameter> items = new ArrayList<>();

Iterator<String> it = node.fieldNames();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   String nextField = it.next();
   JsonNode n = node.get(nextField);
   JsonNode type = n.get("type");
   Parameter p = new Parameter();
   p.setName(nextField);
   p.setType(type.asText());
   items.add(p);
}

return items;
```

The custom serializer would on the other hand loop through the list of parameters and for each one, it will first create a field using the parameter's name and this field would contain an object with one field, namely type, using the parameter's type

```
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();//com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
for (Parameter p : parameters) {
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(p.getName());
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("type", p.getType());
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
}
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
```